# Running Pyspark Without sudo

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark, pyspark

When I run pyspark without `sudo` in the command line in Ubuntu, I get the following error:

> You need to build Spark with the target "package" before running this program.

But there is not any problem when running with `sudo` and get the command line of spark.

I have added the spark into the path up to now.

Comment: How did you deployed Spark?

Comment: @user9613318 Download the prebuilt version of the spark.

Comment: Based on the symptoms you did that as root. Any reason for that? If you want to keep this as is, just fix the permissions (at least +rx for user / group you want to use to submit Spark applications).

Comment: @user9613318 up to now, I've added `chmod 777` to the specified folder of unzipped spark. isn't enough?

Comment: It should be at least recursive.

Comment: @user9613318 it was `chmod 777 spark_folder -R`. but not mentioned in the comment. is it enough? the same problem.

Comment: `chmod -R 777 spark_folder`, right?

Comment: @user9613318 right.